# Jenkins Pipelien groovy string comparison not working

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I am having a shared library in which there is a groovy script, that returns the status as 'FAIL' or 'SUCCESS' at the end.I am using the status to FAIL the jenkins build if needed. Following is small snippet :

```
def res=generateStats()
            print(' build result '+res)
                         if(res == "FAIL")
            {
            print(' enter1 ')    
             currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            }
            else
            print('no2')
            
            
                 if(res == 'FAIL')
            {
            print(' enter3 ')    
             currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            }
            else
            print('no23')

Output is :
17:41:51  build result FAIL                                    
[Pipeline] echo
17:41:51 no2
[Pipeline] echo
17:41:51 no23
```

Why the code is not going in if branch and failing the pipeline? I used two if blocks to just test double or single quotes.The print statements are added to debug only

Comment: What is coming from `generateStats()`? What happens when you trim that return value `def res = generateStats().trim()`? I assumed you wrote if statement in your pipeline with correct syntax / closures etc as above snippet is not correct.

Comment: thanks,it worked.I padded my response in backend with spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try using string comparators `.equal()` instead of using `==`

Comment: equals also did not work.i paded some spaces at backend in status.i removed those and it worked fine.thanks.